# Covariance in Tagged Type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I've created such tagged types from Miles Sabin gist example:

```
  type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
  type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

  sealed trait A
  sealed trait E
  sealed trait B extends E
  sealed trait C extends E
  def a(a: String): String @@ A = a.asInstanceOf[String @@ A]
  def b(a: String): String @@ B = a.asInstanceOf[String @@ B]
  def c(a: String): String @@ C = a.asInstanceOf[String @@ C]
```

I have a method:

```
 def f(e: String @@ E) = ???
```

I want this method to take both `String @@ B` and `String @@ C` types since both `B` and `C` extend `E`. How can I do it? I tried to make `@@` covariant:

```
type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
type @@[T, +U] = T with Tagged[U]
```

but it doesn't help - I can only pass objects of type `String @@ E`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```scala
def f[T <: E](e: String @@ T) = println(e)
f(b("1")) // 1
f(c("2")) // 2
```

?